# How can I include a subdomain in my htaccess that forces HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess

There is an htaccess file in the root directory of my domain.  I added a subdomain called dev so I can work on the application from there.  I think the htacccess file is preventing me from visiting the subdomain because it is rewriting the url to the main domain.  How can I add a rule that rewrites the url of the subdomain to HTTPS?  The main domain still works fine but I get Error 500 when I visit `dev.{site_name}.php` and `{site_name.ph}/dev` The url of the subdomain would be `https://www.{site_name}.ph`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^{site_name}\.ph [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.{site_name}.ph/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: you only match the literal name `{site_name}`, because you anchored the string match with `^`. if you want subdomains, maybe you'd want something more like `{site_name}.\ph$` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to force `http->https` in all the domains:

```
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```